# Changing target Android device in Intellij Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm writing my application to two different physical devices. For the first 'Run' session, I'm prompted to choose which device I'd like to run the application on. On further clicks of 'Run', it assumes the device I chose on the first run.

If I want to write to the second device, I have to unplug the first device (and then later plug it back in if I want to view its log).

Is there a way I can change my target device without having to unplug the first device?

Comment: So you're saying that you have two Android devices plugged into your computer, but Android Studio keeps recognizing the first one? (I ask because folks on, e.g. a Mac Book, might only have a single USB port).

Comment: you have to quit your application from your current active device then run it again now it will show u the list of connected devices without unplugging any device

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Macbook, but 2 USBs. My IDE (Intellij Idea) recognises both devices, but running my application of each device is a little bit of a chore.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well your request, you probably clicked on "use the same device for future launches" when you launched your app for the first time, to solve your problem try this :

In Android studio go to `Menu -> Run -> Edit Configurations`

Then, in `app` tab uncheck "Use same device for future launches"
Now for future launches, you'll be prompted to choose a device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I had selected 'USB Device' as my target deployment, which didn't have that checkbox. However I changed to the 'Open Select Deployment Target Dialog' option and fixed the issue.

Comment: This has made my life a bit easier, but the issue still stands that once I've clicked 'Run' once, clicking it again automatically builds to the same device and doesn't offer me to choose a different device.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Run Menu and select Edit Configuration:

[image: Edit configuration]

2.Choose your app and untick the `Use Same Device for future launches`

[image: future launch]

3. Click on Apply